# QJsonDocument giving null when converting from Qvariant?

Tags: json, qt, qjson

```
#include "QtCore"
#include "QMap"
#include "qdebug.h"
#include "qjsondocument.h"



class cclass{
public:
    int var;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(cclass);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

cclass object1;
object1.var=40;

 QVariant variant= QVariant::fromValue(object1);


  QVariantMap map;
    map.insert("variant",variant);



 QJsonDocument document=  QJsonDocument::fromVariant(map);

 qDebug()<<document;

    return a.exec();
}
```

qdebug returns `QJsonDocument({"variant":null})` 
I think it should be returning the values of object1 but it returns null.why so?
I want to pair string and a class in json using qt.how can i do it

Comment: from [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromVariant) `If the variant contains any other type than a QVariantMap, QVariantHash, QVariantList or QStringList, the returned document is invalid.`

Comment: but its a qvariatmap only

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way *QVariant* handles **custom types**.

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue), `Note: If you are working with custom types, you should use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro to register your custom type.`

In other words, *QVariant::fromValue()* doesn't know what to do with your *cclass* type and simply create a null QVariant, which is then serialized accordingly in the *QJsonDocument*.

Comment: I already declared Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() see below my class declaration and also Qvariant has  value.I already checked with qdebug. problem is its showing null in Qjsondocument